# Use variable as entity table name

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is there a way to dynmaically define the table name so I do not have to do multiple calls if the table I'm accessing is different for different conditions? I don't want to have an if/else for every table I am accessing if I can use a variable name instead.

```
using (Entity ctx = new Entity())
{
    dbTableVal = "EntityTables";
    var query = from d in dbTableVal
                where d == "Yes"
                select d;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess no, because the table itself also defines the type of returned `IQueryable<T>`. It is even not possible with ESQL (which has string syntax) to define generic query where you don't know the type of result set.

Comment: Yeah, I tried making this work as a variable, but found that I'm only doing three tables, so I used a switch instead of trying to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below:

[Using LINQ to SQL with Dynamic tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714401/using-linq-to-sql-with-dynamic-tables)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a function that accepts an "object" and "type" and returns an IQUeryable ?

eg:

```
private IQueryable GetQuery(object Table, Type t)
{
    var query = from d in ((t)Table) where d == "Yes" select d;
    return query;
}
```

UNTESTED!!! so may need to do some variation on that, but something along those lines might work for you....

Comment: I think your method signature would need to be private IQueryable GetQuery<t>(object Table) if you want to use the type in order to do a cast like that.